# Scenekit scnbillboard and lookatconstraints conflict

Tags: scenekit

I'm trying to point a circle with arrow at the top at an scnnode in scenekit, but keep it constrained or flat toward the point of view at all times.  It seems that with a look at constraint, the billboard constraint gets ignored.

Here is the setup for constraints:

```
let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint ()
billboardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y 

let lookatConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint ( target: targetNode )
lookatConstraint.localFront = SCNVector3Make ( 0, 1, 0 )
lookatConstraint.worldUp = SCNVector3Make ( 0, 1, 0 )

arrowNode.constraints = [billboardConstraint, lookatConstraint]

self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode ( arrowNode )
```

Here are example images of the issue.  The first image is how I want to keep it, the second image shows the flattening that I can't seem to control:

[image: Ok]

[image: NOT OK]

No matter what I try, it doesn't stay facing the camera.  I've tried equating the z distance for both the arrow node and the target node (still rotates the arrow node undesirably), tried setting a gimbal lock (flips the arrow node out), tried to adjust the angles for the arrow node to keep it "facing" the point of view, and tried an SCNCone as a pointer.

I also tried just moving this arrow node into an imageview in the overlay, with an invisible arrow node inside Scenekit, but couldn't get the math right when trying to CGAffineTransform the 2d UIImageView.  I tried getting the rotation vector for the SCNNode that has the SCNLookatConstraint, tried projectpoint, etc.  Not quite getting it. Maybe I should've paid more attention in high school :-(

Anyone have any ideas:

Answer (score 0):

This post: 59251351 - it's like a 3d box with a tube (a tank with a gun), that targets a specific node - "aims" at it.  That's your arrow, so first - make sure that you have set it up with the correct rotation from the beginning, otherwise it will never work.  Arrow should be a subnode so that your main node and all subnodes rotate together as you set the constraints for the main node.

The example is a fixed -z for related nodes and the point of view doesn't change.  Assuming you want to move the camera forward, then you need a way to maintain perspective - that's keeping Z for all in question at the same distance from the camera.

So, if your target node and indicator can stay on the same z distance plane (as you indicated in your example that it can work that way), I "think" this should help.  You might set your target node slightly off on z compared to your arrrow nodes, something insignificant such as .001 - just so the lookAt math doesn't actually return a (NAN) though some happenstance.

If it's more complex than that, then someone with more math skills is required.
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response Voltan.  I couldn't quite get it working yet using your technique in the other post.  But how about if I just move the circle with arrow into a UIImageView in the overlay?  How could I point the arrow at the scenekit target node (how to translate the position and apply cgaffinetransform, either from a lookatconstraint on an invisible scenekit node, or just from the position of the target node itself)?

Comment: Interesting idea - l like the imageview option - you can translate 3d to 2d with projectPoint.  Then you have a 2d point (assumes in your view port I guess, never tried it without being in the window) - then do your transform in 2d coordinates.  Sounds feasible- but not sure exactly how accurate it would be.